# Flattening a list of sublists and individual elements

Tags: python

I have a list of sublists and elements. I want to flatten the list such that only the sublists within the list are split and added to the list.

```
[['item1','item2'],['item3','item4','item5'],'item6']
```

I have tried the following

```
[item for sublist in [['item1','item2'],['item3','item4','item5'],'item6'] for item in sublist]
```

results in:

```
['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'i', 't', 'e', 'm', '6']
```

However, I want it to result in:

```
['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your list is called `X`. You can do this with a simple `for` loop:

```py
y = []
for x in X:
    if isinstance(x, list): y.extend(x)
    else: y.append(x)

print(y) # ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6']
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists), `x.extend(y)` appends all elements of `y` to `x`.

Answer (score 3):

This solution is taken from the book Python Cookbook, chapter 4, problem 14, which returns a generator

```
from collections import Iterable
def flatten(items, ignore_types=(str, bytes)):
  for x in items:
    if isinstance(x, Iterable) and not isinstance(x, ignore_types):
      yield from flatten(x)
    else:
      yield x
nested = [['item1','item2'],['item3','item4','item5'],'item6']
res = list(flatten(nested))
print(res)
```